# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'phone' cannot be null - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

When uploading an excel file into my database, i get this error because the phone field is required. When i upload a file with the required headers(row), the file upload successfully but then when i upload a file which doesn't have the row the code requires, i get this error 
`Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'phone' cannot be null - Laravel`.

Is there a way i could probably check the rows before so as to  handle the error?

```
 if($request->file('imported-file'))
    {
              $path = $request->file('imported-file')->getRealPath();

              $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader)
              {
                 $reader->calculate(false);

              })->get();

        if(($request->file('imported-file')->getClientOriginalExtension()) != 'xlsx')
        {
            return redirect('/')->with('error','File Format may not be supported');

        }
        else {
            if(!empty($data) && $data->count())
            {
              foreach ($data->toArray() as $row)
              {
                if(!empty($row))
                {
                  $dataArray[] =
                  [
                    'name' => array_get($row, 'name'),
                    'phone' => array_get($row, 'phone'),
                  ];
                }

            }
            if(!empty($dataArray))
            {
               People::insert($dataArray);

               return redirect('')->with('status','Clients successfully added');
             }
           }
        }     
 }
 else {
    return redirect('/')->with('error','No file was uploaded. Please upload a file');

 }

}
```

Comment: The easy solution would be to make your database field nullable, unless you require a phone number to be present.

Comment: Yes i  do require a phone number @Jeffrey

Comment: Then check if 'phone' is present in your array using `isset($row['phone'])`.

Comment: @Jeffrey  Wouldn't it throw the errorException page when the phone is absent in the row? That is what i want to handle with a nicer error the user to understand

Comment: No, `isset()` doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: What about checking with isset($dataArray['phone']) right before People::insert ?

Comment: @Amarnasan, thanks a lot!!